# Combining information from two lists

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have two List objects, one recording passes and one recording failures for parts. I build two separate lists because they are displayed separately in an Excel spreadsheet.

Both lists contain `ReportData` objects, which have fields:

```
DataDate (DateTime)
quantity (int)
rejected (int)
cumulativeQuantity (int)
cumulativeRejected (int)
```

In the pass list, I record the date, the quantity, and the cumulativeQuantity passed up to that date. The rejected and cumulativeRejected values are set to zero. I do the opposite for the failed list.

At the end, I would like to combine them to get one `List<ReportData>` object that has all of the dates.

I do not want to intersect the lists, because technically there are no intersections. While the date may exist in both, the objects are not the same. I considered looping through the pass list, and looking for dates that exist in the failures, and then recording their rejected and cumulativeRejected values. The issue this leads to is that if there are dates that do not exist, I may not know what to set `cumulativeRejected` to for that date.

Another problem is if an item exists in failures but not passes. In practice, this *shouldn't* happen, but for intents and purposes of this example it could.

Is there a way to do this? It's almost a combination of both an intersect and a union of lists, and I don't know what to do.

**EDIT**

If that is a little unclear, consider two lists:

```
pass:
   DataDate: 05/01/15 quantity: 10 cumQuantity: 10 rejected: 0 cumRejected: 0
   DataDate: 05/02/15 quantity: 15 cumQuantity: 25 rejected: 0 cumRejected: 0
   DataDate: 05/03/15 quantity: 10 cumQuantity: 35 rejected: 0 cumRejected: 0
   DataDate: 05/04/15 quantity: 15 cumQuantity: 50 rejected: 0 cumRejected: 0

fail:
   DataDate: 05/01/15 quantity: 0 cumQuantity: 0 rejected: 10 cumRejected: 10
   DataDate: 05/02/15 quantity: 0 cumQuantity: 0 rejected: 10 cumRejected: 20
   DataDate: 05/03/15 quantity: 0 cumQuantity: 0 rejected: 10 cumRejected: 30
   DataDate: 05/05/15 quantity: 0 cumQuantity: 0 rejected: 10 cumRejected: 40
```

How can I obtain a final list that looks like this:

```
total:
   DataDate: 05/01/15 quantity: 10 cumQuantity: 10 rejected: 10 cumRejected: 10
   DataDate: 05/02/15 quantity: 15 cumQuantity: 25 rejected: 10 cumRejected: 20
   DataDate: 05/03/15 quantity: 10 cumQuantity: 35 rejected: 10 cumRejected: 30
   DataDate: 05/04/15 quantity: 15 cumQuantity: 50 rejected: 0 cumRejected: 30
   DataDate: 05/05/15 quantity: 0 cumQuantity: 50 rejected: 10 cumRejected: 40
```

Comment: What is unclear about what I'm asking?

Comment: `List<ReportData>` is what you want.. can you show what the class structure of you code looks like.. what you have posted in regards to code is not valid C# code.. please show all relevant code as it pertains to your question.. what is the 5 lines of code that you have shown.. what's does that represent..???

Comment: Loop thru the dates you are insterested in, within a loop call GetReportData(Date, Passed, Failed) returning ReportData.

Comment: @MethodMan I was trying not to bulk up the question. The class is just those four fields, I have listed their names and types. The collection is just a `List<ReportData>` object. I have edited the question to show the information that might appear in two different lists, and what I want the final list to look like.

Comment: I dont know much about lists in C#.. But how about doing something like this? 

Use the Except method to get the differences between Pass and Failed based on Date. 

Intersect Pass and Fail.

Union the Except result with Intersect??

Comment: is the same index of the each list should be the same merged object?

Comment: @FelipeOriani I don't understand your question. The date should be unique in the final list, so if a date exists in both pass and fail its information can be merged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this (not the most efficient but short and clear):

```
var combined = passed
    .Concat(failed)
    .GroupBy(x => x.DataDate)
    .Select(x => new ReportData {
        DataDate = x.Key,
        quantity = x.Sum(rd => rd.quantity),
        rejected = x.Sum(rd => rd.rejected),
        cumulativeQuantity = x.Max(rd => rd.cumulativeQuantity), // or Sum
        cumulativeRejected = x.Max(rd => rd.cumulativeRejected)  // or Sum
    }).ToList();

// Fill "holes" for dates not present in both lists.
for (var i = 1; i < combined.Count; i++)
{
    if (combined[i].cumulativeQuantity == 0)
        combined[i].cumulativeQuantity = combined[i - 1].cumulativeQuantity;
    if (combined[i].cumulativeRejected == 0)
        combined[i].cumulativeRejected = combined[i - 1].cumulativeRejected;
}
```

Comment: Really great idea, and I like the way you handle filling the gaps. It will be a while before I can test this for sure, but I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Alex's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30058769/209259), so I'll expand on it:

(Dictionaries can speed up processing if your date ranges are huge, so they are here for example.  This also assumes there are **no duplicate dates**.  If there are let me know, I'll adjust it accordingly)

This assumes you're two types aren't compatible [The `<TSource>` is not the same](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
var passedDict = passed.ToDictionary(p => p.DataDate, p);
var failedDict = failed.ToDictionary(p => p.DataDate, p);

var startedOn = DateTime.....
var endedOn = DateTime....

var combined = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 1 + endedOn.Subtract(startedOn).Days)
  .Select(x => 
    {
      Pass pass;
      Fail fail;

      var result = new ReportData()
      result.DataDate = staredOn.AddDays(x),

      if (passedDict.TryGetValue(result.DataDate, out pass))
      {
        result.Quantity = pass.Quantity;
        result.CumulativeQuantity = pass.CumulativeQuantity;
      }

      if (failedDict.TryGetValue(result.DataDate, out fail))
      {
        result.Rejected= fail.Rejected;
        result.CumulativeRejected = fail.CumulativeRejected ;
      }

      return result;
    })
  .ToList();
```